# Variables automatically changes its value

Tags: freepascal

I'm doing this question with Pascal (Google Kick Start 2020 Round A - Workout) and I ran into a problem that doesn't make any sense at all. Here is a part of my program:

```
var N,K,i,max,max1 : longint;
    M : array [1..100000] of longint;
    A : array [1..99999] of longint;
begin
        readln(N,K);
        for i := 1 to N do
        read(M[i]);

        for i := 1 to N-1 do A[i] := M[i+1]-M[i];
        max := 0;
        for i := 1 to N-1 do
        if A[i] >= max then
        begin
                max := A[i];
                max1 := i;
        end;

        writeln('max = ',max); writeln('max1 = ',max1);
        readln; readln;
end.
```

So first I type in all the input data which are:
5 6 and
9
10
20
26
30.
When I run the program, the value of *max* is 10 and the value of *max1* is 2.

But when I change the way *max* gets its value and totally did nothing with *max1*, the program becomes like this:

```
uses crt;
var N,K,i,max,max1 : longint;
    M : array [1..100000] of longint;
    A : array [1..99999] of longint;
begin
        readln(N,K);
        for i := 1 to N do
        read(M[i]);

        for i := 1 to N-1 do A[i] := M[i+1]-M[i];
        max := 0;
        for i := 1 to N-1 do
        if A[i] >= max then
        begin
                max := i;
                max1 := i;
        end;

        writeln('max = ',max); writeln('max1 = ',max1);
        readln; readln;
end.
```

I run the program, and suddenly both the values of *max* and *max1* are 4. How can this happen? Should I delete Pascal?? By the way if you can't install Pascal for some reasons then go to this link:https://www.onlinegdb.com/, select Pascal language and paste my program. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: By assigning i to max, and then using that in comparison with A items, you changed your program's logic. Probably no need to delete Pascal yet ;)

Comment: As a rule, when you see something you can't explain you should suspect yourself as being the culprit. It's exceptionally rare to fine compiler defects. On the other hand, human mistakes are all too common.

Comment: I don't understand why you are surprised. What should the result be in your opinion and why?

Comment: I'm surprised because I don't understand why max1 changed its value, the only difference between the programs is the value of max. So why did max1 have 2 different results in 2 programs? Maybe I misread it somewhere?

Comment: You are not considering that you have a conditional branch that depends on `max`. OTOH, the value of `max` is assigned different values in the two programs. Step through both programs separately in the debugger and make notes about what values you have in `A[]` and `max` on each round in the `for` loop.